# What makes the mixing of two fluids turbulent?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

I am trying to grasp an intuitive idea for the formation of turbulence. Looking at the expression for the Reynold's number, I can see why increasing the flow rate of a fluid leads to turbulent behavior. However, I am struggling to see what is behind the spawn of turbulence when two fluids are mixed even though variables such as the flow rate and the characteristic dimension are held constant. Two everyday examples that come to mind are

1. Coffee being mixed with milk
2. Smoke coming off a cigarrete

Why do events such as these lead to turbulent flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turbulence is an innate characteristic of fluid flows. Flows in nature are almost always turbulent; it is how things usually are. Thus, instead of asking why does turbulence develop in certain flows, it would be more appropriate to ask why does it not develop in some special cases.

Though to answer your question directly, at the most fundamental level, turbulence is due to the non-linearity of fluid dynamics. The second term in the left-hand side of Navier-Stokes equation:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}-\frac{\mu}{\rho}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},$$
which is known as the "convective acceleration" term, is non-linear (it is the product of velocity with velocity gradient). This non-linearity is what makes Navier-Stokes impossible to solve analytically in many cases, and causes the chaotic behavior of flows we recognize as turbulence. If the flow velocity is too small, the non-linear term becomes negligible compared to the other terms, and this causes the flow to become laminar.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee mixed with milk is largely due to thermodynamics.  The coffee is hot the milk is cold.  When mixed the temperature gradient is not uniform and the motion of the fluids is largely driven simply by the temperature difference between different regions in the mixture.

Smoke coming off a cigarette is largely due to the airflow in the room, which once again is driven partially by thermodynamics (as well as other factors).  The airflow of the surrounding environment is what creates the turbulent pattern of the smoke.

Comment: So in both cases the transition to turbulent flow is a result of a temperature gradient? If so, why is the cigarette smoke initially laminar?

Comment: Initially the cigarette smoke is quite hot, compared to the surrounding air, and therefore rises quickly in a nearly laminar flow.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any more resource recommendations that explain the explore turbulence as a result of a temperature gradient?